# Подсветка синтаксиса по умолчанию Sublime для файлов начинающихся на #!/usr/bin/perl

Tags: perl, sublime-text, settings, sublime-text-3

Поставил Modern​Perl так как стандартная не подсвечивала переменные в текстовых строках.

```
    "extensions": 
[
    "pl", 
    "PL", 
    "pm", 
    "pod", 
    "t"
]
```

Внёс настройки, которые выше. Но! Для файлов, которые не имеют расширение .pl и так далее, подсветка определяется по интерпретатору в начале файла #!/usr/bin/perl и выбирается стандартная Perl, а мне нужна моя дополнительная ModernPerl. Как ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не нужна поддержка стандартной подсветки Perl, то можно ее отключить:

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> ⇒ `Package Control: Disable Package` ⇒ `Perl`

Если после этого заново открыть файл без расширения, то должен подхватиться ModernPerl.

Альтернативный вариант:

В папке, в которую был установлен Sublime Text, нужно найти папку Packages (это **не** та папка, которую можно открыть с помощью `Preferences` ⇒ `Browse Packages`, а конкретно папка Sublime Text); я не берусь точно сказать, где она будет лежать на вашем компьютере. В этой папке `Packages` должен будет лежать файл `Perl.sublime-package` - это "архив", содержащий конфигурации для стандартной темы Perl. Необходимо зайти в этот архив и открыть для редактирования файл `Perl.tmLanguage`, найти в нем строчки

```
<key>firstLineMatch</key>
<string>^#!.*\bperl\b</string>
```

удалить их и сохранить файл, после чего переоткрыть Sublime Text. В файле без расширения должен подхватиться ModernPerl.

Как можно заметить, эта опция отвечает за определение синтаксиса по первой строке в файле, под что `#!/usr/bin/perl` собственно и подпадает. Эта опция имеет одно и то же значение как в стандартной подсветке Perl, так и в ModernPerl, но почему ModernPerl не ставится в приоритет я пока разобраться не смог.

Comment: Благодарочка. Великолепно !

Comment: Всё, класс, кроме того, что я чуть не разбил клавиатуру, потому как он просто перестал комментировать строки, просто взял и перестал, а потом, я понял, что перестал после отключения Perl и перезапуска, он теперь напрочь забыл как же комментируются строки в Perl... Есть ещё варианты? Иначе мне становится непонятным как люди пользуются этой поделкой и почему так восхваляют, если с такими стандартными запросами уже возникают проблемы

Comment: А со включенным Perl все работает корреткно? Видимо имеет место какое-то наследование функционала. Я добавил в ответ альтернативный вариант, потребуется модификация исходных файлов Sublime Text, но не уверен что проблема с комментариями решится.

Comment: Да, с включенным пакетом Perl всё работает, но приходится переключать каждый раз на ModernPerl) Спасибо за подробный ответ, сейчас попробую на маке найти куда он засовывает настройки Sublime, думаю grep -R мне в этом поможет ... ) как сделаю, отпишусь